# Sum of decimal nullable and decimal values

Tags: c#

Why after this code execution variable 'a' contains **null** and not 10?

```
decimal? a = null;
a += 10;
```

Comment: I'm going to assume that `null` means here `nothing` and not `zero`... Since mathematics (usually) does not work with `nothing` but with values, you won't get the result your expect. This, as mentioned in the answers and comments, is therefore reflected in the language specification.

Comment: Why should it contains `10`? If it was so - then `null` should be treated as `0` - but it's not true.

Comment: Spec says so. If one of the operand is `null` result is always null.

Comment: @SoMoS Perhaps the downvoters were focusing on the *other* reasons: "does not show any research effort; isn't useful" rather than just the singular one of being clear or not.

Comment: I agree with @SoMoS. This is a valid question and should not be downvoted because it's a _beginner_ question.

Comment: The question doesn't show research effort, it has nothing to do with whether its a "beginner" question.

Comment: @Sayse I don't know how much programming experience the OP has but I'm willing to bet that a junior developer would not know how and what to look for (let alone in the specs...).

Comment: I made a 'research' and did not found any similar question. Anyway, thanks for all your comments!

Comment: @AndreiV - "I searched for C# X and found Y but that doesn't explain Z because..." anything along those lines would suffice, Incidentally the first result for "C# null" is for msdn which gives a link to nullable types in the first sentence which then has a subsection for using nullable types which is where the answer came from

Comment: So what exactly could happen when you do a `IEnumerable<int?>.Sum()`??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't add a value to `null`. `null` will be null whatever value you add to it. On the other hand if you had assigned non null value to `a` the 10 would have been added to `a`.

Taken from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx)

> The predefined unary and binary operators and any user-defined
>   operators that exist for value types may also be used by nullable
>   types. These operators produce a null value if the operands are null;
>   otherwise, the operator uses the contained value to calculate the
>   result. For example:

```
int? a = 10;
int? b = null;

a++;         // Increment by 1, now a is 11.
a = a * 10;  // Multiply by 10, now a is 110.
a = a + b;   // Add b, now a is null.
```

Comment: Also, it is worth to say that OP can use `Nullable<T>.GetValueOrDefault` to get the object's default value which will be 0 for `decimal`.

Comment: exception is `bool?`. `false | null` produces `null`, but `true | null` produces `true`.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez thanks for your comment I will update correspondingly my asnwer.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev thanks for your comment I will update correspondingly my asnwer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know for c#, but in SQL, Null + value = Null, so that seems normal to me. In VBA I use Nz(myNum,0) to return 0 if myNum is Null, otherwise it returns myNum

Answer (score 2):

**Null** means "*unknown*", "*has no meaning*", "*unapplicable*" etc. So in your case

```
  // "Unknown" + 10 = ? 
  decimal? a = null;
  a += 10; // Still "Unknown"...
```

The *same* thing with *databases*, e.g. Oracle sample:

```
  select null + 10 -- null
    from Dual
```

Answer (score 1):

decimal? is not a decimal. It is a nullable struct.
When you are using + operator, your nullable<> get converted to decimal. Result of that operation is stored in new nullable<>.
But, If one value is null (HasValue==false, nothing is there!) then you simply cannot perform binary operation.

You should get warning:
Warning 111 The result of the expression is always 'null' of type 'decimal?

Answer (score 0):

Because a null means a null reference. Meaning `a` does not point to an object. So there is no object to add 10 to.

If `a` was 0 then `a` would point to an object and 0 + 10 would equal 10 like you are expecting

**From [null (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edakx9da.aspx):**

> The null keyword is a literal that represents a null reference, one
>   that does not refer to any object. null is the default value of
>   reference-type variables. Ordinary value types cannot be null.
>   However, C# 2.0 introduced nullable value types

Comment: Not quite true. That's a nullable decimal, which means the *value* is null. It still points to an object.